# rosrun and finding python files in other packages using catkin

Tags: python, catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked a similar question and got it to work with global scripts but not with rosrun.

So now I wonder how to do the following:

In package A i have

A/src/mp.py

In package B I have a file

A/src/test.py

which has the line:

```
from mp import *
```

Now when I do "rosrun A test.py" mp.py is not found. What is the correct way to solve this. Exactly what should I write in setup.py and in CMakeFile.txt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57022/rosrun-and-finding-python-files-in-other-packages-using-catkin/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In setup.py of package A, you need to export the module. The cleanest way is to use a python package. So you should put mp.py in a python package, like

```
A/
A/setup.py
A/src/
A/src/mp/
A/src/mp/__init__.py
A/src/mp/mp.py
```

Then in setup.py declare the package mp, and enable the line catkin_python_setup() in A's CMakeLists.txt. Then run catkin_make. This will generate package relay files, in devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/A. Then source devel/setup.sh. This will change your PYTHONPATH to include the package relay files.

See:

http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html

http://ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-03-04**:
OK. So the thing that was possible  with rosbuild is no longer possible. That should be documented somewhere since I have wasted some time trying to figure out how to get it to work as with rosbuild.  I need to read up on Python packages I see.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-03-04**:
Got it to work. Thanks for the good answer.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-03-05**:
Is the package fund before system packages? I have a package called tst but the import seems to select "/usr/share/doc/python-libxml2/examples/tst.py". I solved my problem with "import tst.tst" but it was very confusing.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-03-05**:
That's how python does it, and that's why it is best to always use packages, and to always import giving the full name with the package.